# Angular 5 Inheritance / Function Overriding Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, overriding

I am trying to create a simple prototype of component inheritance with function overriding using Angular 5. I have created very simple PrototypeParent and PrototypeChild components, where the child extends the parent. I am triggering the call to the overridden function both through a button in the parent's HTML, and through the parent's typescript itself. In both cases, it is **not** calling the overridden function in the child, but instead calling the function in the parent component.

When I navigate to the page through the browser, I am navigating to the child. Note that I am using transclusion (ng-content) for the HTML composition of the page, in case that affects anything.

**prototype-parent.component.ts:**

```
export class PrototypeParentComponent {

  screenbeanParent: PrototypeParentBean;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  functionOverride() {
    console.log("functionOverride() called in Parent");
  }

  functionA() {
    this.functionOverride();
  }
}
```

**prototype-child.component.ts:**

```
export class PrototypeChildComponent extends PrototypeParentComponent {

  screenbeanChild: PrototypeChildBean;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  functionOverride() {
    console.log("functionOverride() called in Child");
  }
}
```

**prototype-parent.component.html:**

```
<form id="prototypeParent" class="form-horizontal">
    <div id="header" class="col-sm-12" header-panel>
      <div id="headerPnl" class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Parent Header Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <button (click)="functionOverride()">functionOverride()</button>
          <button (click)="functionA()">functionA()</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body" class="col-sm-12">
      <ng-content select="[prototype-body]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="col-sm-12" footer-panel>
      <div id="footerPnl" class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Parent Footer Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          Angular Function Message:
          <label id="message">{{screenbeanParent.message}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**prototype-child.component.html:**

```
<div id="prototypeChild">
  <app-prototype-parent>
    <div id="childPnl" class="panel panel-primary" prototype-body>
      <div class="panel-heading">Child Component Title</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <button (click)="functionOverride()">functionOverride()</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app-prototype-parent>
</div>
```

Any help or advice as to why the function overriding is not working would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you put this up on StackBlitz pls? [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: I know that this is an angular question, but take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html Important quote:  `At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies.`

Comment: @RandyCasburn I added the code to StackBlitz here: https://angular-cr1di4.stackblitz.io , same is occurring, when I click the buttons it calls the parent instead of the overridden child functionOverride()

Comment: @TomaszKula Our case is very particular. We are modernizing a legacy application into a modern web application. The legacy application has deep inheritance trees on the UI components. Thus inheritance on the component side is necessary for us to replicate this. We have done this successfully in AngularJS, but this is the first try on Angular 2+.

Comment: This is so far outside the design concepts of an Angular app I won't go here. Read up on Angular's architecture and style guide. The entire framework was written to provide you efficient Muti-level integrated componentry that exists by nature in a hierarchy. Good luck.

Comment: @RandyCasburn This link may be more useful as you can see the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cr1di4?file=prototype%2Fprototype-child.component.ts

Comment: Let me reiterate after your comment: The entire framework was designed to accomplish your goal. It just does it in a way that you don't care to implement properly. You should use React.

Comment: I have seen the code - that is where I form my opinion.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks for the response. Would there be another way that you know of that could accomplish the following without inheritance? Re-usable components that can be developed without knowing the details of any "child" components that may need to use the functionality later

Comment: Your thinking is pigeon holed into a single way of thinking about your problem. You see a UI hierarchy while Angular projects a Component Hierarchy. If the Child Component needs to execute an internal method, then do that - it needs nothing from the Parent Component. Otherwise. if the parent Component needs to execute an internal method, then do that. You see, in a Component hierarchy each component is as independent as you need them to be. In a UI hierarchy there is an intrinsic binding between parent and child where one must compete with the other. Angular removes this competition.